# Apache Netbeans 12.4 with eclipseLink 2.1 / Payara Server 5.20 - Converter class specified was not found

Tags: eclipselink, payara

The goal is to use persistence with a class that contains a geometry information and to store this information into an Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY field.

Tools used :

- Apache Netbeans 12.4 with eclipseLink 2.1 driver
- Payar Server 5.2021 for application deployment

The class calls a class transformer to transform JGeometry type to MDSYS_SDO_GEOMETRY expected by Oracle if I understand well. It looks like :

- Adresse.java class with converter call: [java class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqxmZ.png)
- My persistence file looks like : [persistence.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Q2l.png)

I used "eclipselink.classloader" but it seems not to solve the problem.

When executing the appplication  the server returns this error :

Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [com.spt_adressagenumerique_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7351] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description:
**The converter class** [org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.converters.JGeometryConverter] specified on the mapping attribute [position_gps] from the class [com.spt.database.Adresse]
**was not found. Please ensure the converter class name is correct and exists with the persistence unit definition**.

Comment: Was it not able to find the org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.converters.JGeometryConverter itself, or was it the unable to load the class due to not being able to find some spatial dependencies? You'll need to check the root exception for which is the case. JGeometryConverter  comes from EclipseLink jars - you'll have to verify you have the proper one with the class on your class path (org.eclipse.persistence.oracle). The Oracle dependencies should be in the sdoapi.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the following solution :

1. Use of *eclipse* *IDE 2021-06*
2. Use of *hibernate* instead of *eclipseLink*
3. Use of *hibernate-spatial* and indication of *org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect* in *hibernate.cfg.xml*
4. Creation of a geometry point  *Point G2D* based on org.geolatte.geom
5. Mapping with the same type in the class definition.

With this solution no need to get sdoapi.jar from Oracle installation.

Thanks and may this solution helpful .